# Принудительно добавить кнопку Menu в api > 8

Tags: android, java

Привет всем!
Если приложение не реализовывает actionbar (то есть если minSdkVersion <= 8) то на планшетах и на некоторых устройствах снизу на панели (которые не имеют кнопки "меню")  появляется эта самая кнопка. Выглядит она как три точки, при нажатии на нее пользователь может открыть меню. Так вот, мое приложение реализовывает actionbar, но в actionbar'е этой кнопки быть не должно, а должна она быть снизу на панели. Грубо говоря мне нужно чтобы кнопка меню присутствовала, но не в actionbar'e. Если поставить targetSdkVersion=8 то кнопка появляется. Но при клике на нее ничего не происходит. Затем если добавить следующий код в активити

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mi = menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.settings));
    mi.setIntent(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

То при клике на кнопку вызывается меню, все отлично, но также кнопка меню добавляется в actionbar!

Вопрос: как ее выпилить из actionbar'a?

Нашел следующий метод.

```
public static void addLegacyOverflowButton(Window window) {
    if (window.peekDecorView() == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Must call addLegacyOverflowButton() after setContentView()");
    }

    try {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.class.getField("FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY").getInt(null));
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // Ignore since this field won't exist in most versions of Android
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.d("token", "Could not access FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY in addLegacyOverflowButton()", e);
    }
}
```

Добавляет кнопку даже если targetSdkVersion > 11

Comment: добавить можно, я даже писал уже два раза на хэшкоде. Но такое поведение очень сильно не приветствуется гуглом. То есть, к примеру, попасть в список "рекомендуемых" будет затруднительно.

Comment: Какая кнопка? Плюс? А если сделать её с атрибутом show="always"?

Comment: Нашел метод, который добавляет кнопку даже если targetSdkVersion > 11, но вопрос остается открытым. Как удалить кнопку из actionbar'a, но так чтобы меню открывалось при клике на кнопку в нижней панели? Неужели придется скрывать полностью actionbar, и рисовать layout похожий на actionbar в каждой активити?

Comment: А как Вы собираетесь открывать меню на аппаратах без нижней панели?

Comment: Почти во всех смартфонах на самом устройстве есть кнопка меню.